# Verify combination of inputs at type level - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, casting, typeerror

I have an angular component that takes two inputs; InputA and InputB.

- InputA can have one of these values only: A1, A2, A3.
- InputB can have one of these values only: B1, B2, B3, B4.

The thing is that, business wise, not all InputA values can go with all InputB values.
For instance:

- A1 can go only with B1 and B4.
- A2 can go only with B1, B2 and B3.
- A3 can go only with B1.

How can I perform a type level check that the dev using my component is not using an unexisting combination like for exemple A1 with B2.
I want to show an error in the IDE when dev using my component writes something like this:
`<my-component inputA=A1 inputB=B1></my-component>`

Writing such line doesn't raise a type level error since A1 is a valid value of InputA and B2 is a valid value of InputB. But the combination isn't good.

I already implemented a method to throw a runtime error but it would be better to have the error in the IDE before compiling and executing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you need simple answer:

```
interface Case1 {
    value1: A1;
    value2: B1 | B4;
}

interface Case2 {
    value1: A2;
    value2: B1 | B2 | B3;
}

interface Case3 {
    value1: A3;
    value2: B1;
}

type InputType = Case1 | Case2 | Case3;

class Component {
    @Input() inputVar: InputType;
}
```

You can realize input as "set: function, like:
@Input() set inputB(value) {...}
and do check there, but if you will use 2 inputs => mby you will have problems with sync (inputB can be set before inputA).